# NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName abbreviation shows different Abbreviations on different devices

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I want to display "EDT" on label. I used below line and I found it to be working on iphone6, 6+ and iphone4 (iOS 7.1). But testing it on iPhone5s(iOS 8.2), iPhone5(iOS 7.1) I noticed it showing "GMT-4"

```
NSString *labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"] abbreviation]]
```

Is it device time zone related issue or can someone point out where am I making mistake please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of the timezone which was set on the devices. Different devices had different timezones set and that made this change in

```
[[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"] abbreviation]]
```

Comment: How is this different from what you use in your question? Looks like `[[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"] abbreviation]]` in both cases.

Comment: On one device settings system timezone was United Kingdom and on the other Mumbai. so  [[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"] abbreviation]] calculated accordingly and brought different timezone abbreviation.

Comment: @TomHarrington I just changed the system timezone on all devices to IST and I got same timeZone abbreviation on all devices.